# Created Alert on View, Email containes Fields not in that View

Tags: 2010, list-view, email, alert

Here is the list of fields in my Writer View:

[image]

What I receive in my Email Alert is:

[image]

The fields in the email do not match the fields in the View?

Answer (score 1):

Use a workflow and craft the e-mail yourself using lookups to get exactly the data you wish to display. The ootb alerts are very specific in what they are useful for, your situation is not one of them.

Comment: I have not worked with workflows, I need all users to be able to create their own alerts for the different views.  I am not sure how that would work using a workflow?

Comment: Not a good answer then, workflows require training to use.